# the JAR file C:\Program Files (x86)Android\android-sdk\android15\android.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

has no source attchment. you can attach the source by clicking attach source below.

what should i do. i found different solutions on the web. but it would be nice to find the best solution.
please help out regards
karan

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse , You can find Android Sources Plugin on [Adt-addons](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/)

In ADT >=8.0.0 you can add Android sources to Android container for all your project with installing the Android source feature using http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/ update site After installing the Android source feature all your existing projects as well as new created projects which is targeted for Android 4.0.1, 2.3.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0.1, 1.6 and 1.5 will have attached the source jar.

It may not have Android API Level 15 , may be they will update soon

Comment: Thanks for your response but iam afraid the dexfile.class in the class file editor says "the source attachment does not coontain the source for the file dexfile.class. you can change the source attachment by clicking the change attached source below"

Comment: also  in the console it gets stuck at attempting to connect to the debugger

Comment: also the ddms perspective has a threads window which says threads not available for the selected client. which toolbar button do i press. i know it sounds silly but i just cant locate the toolbar button

Comment: I thought you want to attch source code of android in IDE like Eclipse , If not , sorry , I didn`t understand the question~~

Comment: do you have some idea about the other problems ive written about.i think you were right in your solution but there are other problems as well.please help me out